# using variable as long double to store maximum precision

Tags: c++, precision

I defined a variable as `long double` to use the maximum precision of number `PI`, but when the program gets excecuted, the value of the variable changed to `3.141592653589793116` and lost some precision.

I checked the size of variable , it is same as size of double so that works like double.

I have problem to store this value, not for print that. Now , how can I use `long double` with full precision?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

  int main() {
    //number PI
    long double pi = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950;

    int sz1 = sizeof(long double);
    int sz2 = sizeof(pi);

    cout << sz1 << endl;
    cout << sz2 << endl;
    printf_s("%.20f\n", pi);
    cout << setprecision(20) << pi; 
    return 0;
}
```

//results:
8
8
3.141592653589793116
3.141592653589793116

Comment: `long double` is only going to get you something like 18 decimal digits of precision. [See here for more](http://stackoverflow.com/q/476212/2065121). You also need a "L" suffix on your literal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380653/why-do-you-need-to-append-an-l-or-f-after-a-value-assigned-to-a-c-constant looks like a more relevant previous answer.

Comment: The precision of the floating point types is platform-dependent and not prescribed by the Standard.

Comment: On some platforms `long double` uses x86 80-bit floating point.  You apparently aren't using such a platform.  Read your compiler documentation to see if some optional support is available.  But after getting that right, you still need to deal with the issue whose answer I linked in my first comment.

Comment: Relevant to this question would be "what target system" and "what compiler"?

Comment: I did a quick google search and the best suggestions for use of 80-bit doubles in Windows appear to be "download and use cygwin" instead of the Microsoft compiler.  Is 80-bit enough for you?  And is fast 80-bit worth the trouble of installing cygwin?  Easier and more precise (but slower) results can be had by using some extended precision floating point package.

Comment: target is x86 , and compiler is visual studio 2015

Comment: yes ,80-bit is enough.